# SQL query by date

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

MySql 5.5.

I have a table that represents a work assignment:

```
   empId   jobNo   workDate   hours
     4      441    10/1/2012    10
     4      441     9/1/2012    22
     4      441     8/1/2012     6
```

And one that represents salary:

```
   empId   effDate     rate
     4     10/1/2012    6.50
     4      9/1/2012    5.85
     4      6/1/2012    4.00
```

The salary applies to all work performed on or after the effective date.  So the rate in jun, jul, and aug is 4.00; sep is 5.85, and oct is 6.50.

If I naively query for October's work:

```
   SELECT Work.empId, Work.jobNo, Work.workDate, Work.hours, Salary.effDate, Salary.rate
   FROM Work
   JOIN Salary ON Work.empId = Salary.empId
   WHERE Work.workDate <= '2012-10-01'
      AND Salary.effDate <= Work.workDate
   ORDER BY Work.jobNo ASC, Work.workDate DESC;
```

I do not get what I want.  I get something like

```
   4   441   10/1/2012   10   10/1/2012   6.50
   4   441   10/1/2012   10    9/1/2012   5.85
   4   441   10/1/2012   10    6/1/2012   4.00
   4   441    9/1/2012   22    9/1/2012   5.85
   4   441    9/1/2012   22    6/1/2012   4.00
   4   441    8/1/2012    6    6/1/2012   4.00
```

When I want

```
   4   441   10/1/2012   10   10/1/2012   6.50
   4   441    9/1/2012   22    9/1/2012   5.85
   4   441    8/1/2012    6    6/1/2012   4.00
```

I can't quite wrap my head around how to create the query I want.
The real situation has multiple employees, multiple jobs, obviously.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: sidenote : pay your employees more :X

Comment: Obviously, the data is contrived.  I actually scaled by 0.01.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your actual issue: you want to be able to detect, for each record in Work, what is the corresponding effective rate, according to the work date x salary effective date. When you simply do `Salary.effDate <= WORK.workDate` you get ALL rates before the work date. But you only want the most recent one.

This is a slightly complicated variant of the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem. There are many ways of doing this, here is one:

```
SELECT sel.*, Salary.Rate
FROM
(
     SELECT Work.empId, Work.jobNo, Work.workDate, 
           Work.hours, Max(Salary.effDate) effDate
    FROM WORK
    JOIN Salary ON WORK.empId = Salary.empId
    WHERE WORK.workDate <= '2012-10-01'
       AND Salary.effDate <= WORK.workDate
    GROUP BY WORK.empId, WORK.jobNo, WORK.workDate, WORK.hours
    ORDER BY WORK.jobNo ASC, WORK.workDate DESC
) sel 
INNER JOIN Salary ON sel.empId = Salary.empId 
                  AND sel.EffDate = Salary.EffDate
```

First of all, the inner query detects the most recent salary effective date for each work record. Then, we join that with the Salary again to the rate.

See the working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8647b/6).

Comment: Beat me by a bit.  I'm just not as fast.  I had a Fiddle and everything too.  LOL.  +1'd you.

Comment: Adrian, you got it in one!  Thanks for your very quick and accurate help.

Answer (score 0):

You're using what's called a NATURAL JOIN. Try changing the word "JOIN" to "LEFT JOIN" which should group the results on the left, giving you the desired results.

Comment: Noah, that gave me the same results.  The way I understand LEFT join, it returns all results from the left (Work) table, even if there are no results from the join.  In this case, there are too many results from the join because the right (Rate) table has multiple rates that match the effDate <= workDate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the salary table has a primary or alternate key (unique index) consisting of the columns `empId` and `effDate`, I'd do something like this:

```
select w.empID                   as EMPLOYEE_ID   ,
       w.jobNo                   as JOB_NUMBER    ,
       w.workDate                as DATE_WORKED   ,
       w.hours                   as HOURS_WORKED  ,
       rate.HourlyWage           as HOURLY_WAGE   ,
       w.hours * rate.HourlyWage as WAGES_CHARGED ,
       rate.effDateFrom          as HOURLY_WAGE_EFFECTIVE_DATE
from work w
join ( select sfrom.EmpId   as EmpID ,
              sfrom.rate    as HourlyWage ,
              sfrom.EffDate as effDateFrom ,
              ( select min(Effdate) 
                from salary t
                where t.empId   = sfrom.EmpId
                  and t.effDate > sfrom.EffDate
              ) as effDateThru
              from salary sfrom
     ) rate on rate.empID = w.empID
           and rate.EffDateFrom <= w.workDate
           and (    rate.effDateThru is null      -- if rate has not end date, is the current period
                 or rate.effDateThru > w.workDate -- 'date-thru' represents the start date of the next period, so the this upper bound is EXCLUSIVE
               )
```

we join the work table against a virtual `rate` table that gives us each employee's wage and the date range for which it is effective. The 'current' row for each employee will have the thru/expiry date set to `null`. And...since the thru/expiry date is actually the effective date for the next salary entry, the upper bound is exclusive rather than inclusive. Consequently, the range test must test for null and one can't use `between`.